# Not able to map JSON response to POJO from com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey, jersey-1.0

I am trying to map a JSON response to a POJO, Some of the properties (the properties start wit @) are not able to map hence I am getting the following error.

Please find the JSON and Class files, What are changes to be done on the POJO to map all properties form the below mentioned JSON?

**JSON**

```
{
  "@customerId": "123456",
  "customerName": "Jobin",
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderId": "bvbundle002075",
      "address": {
        "@elid": "35475908"
      },

    }
  ]
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType
public class CustomerData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9163262900343406982L;

    private String customerId;
    private String customerName;
    private List<Order> orders;

    @XmlElement(name = "@customerId")
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(final String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }


    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(final String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setExistingProducts(final List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
class Order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String orderId;
    private Address address;

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(final String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(final Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String elid;

    @XmlElement(name = "@elid")
    public String getElid() {
        return elid;
    }

    public void setElid(String elid) {
        this.elid = elid;
    }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: null
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalJAXBElementFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:100)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.readFrom(JSONRootElementProvider.java:154)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
    ... 144 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.XmlEventProvider.processTokens(XmlEventProvider.java:421)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.XmlEventProvider.readNext(XmlEventProvider.java:466)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.next(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:506)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(Unknown Source)
    ... 150 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.XmlEventProvider.processTokens(XmlEventProvider.java:315)
```

Comment: You should be using Jackson for JSON Processing. Assuming you are using Jersey 1.x, add the `jersey-json` dependency and configure the `POJOMappingFeature`.

Comment: Yes, We are using Jersy 1.x

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: no, not yet....

Comment: Wanna post your pom.xml, your web.xml, and your client code.

Comment: I resolved it, the problem was that I was using `@XmlElement(name = "@elid")` instead of that I had to use `@XmlAttribute(name = "elid") (note that @ is not required)`,  Thanks @Paul Samsotha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to map an xml attribute to an xml element. If you convert the above JSON which is mentioned in the response which will produce an XML like below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root customerId="123456">
   <customerName>Jobin</customerName>
   <orders>
      <element>
         <address elid="35475908" />
         <orderId>bvbundle002075</orderId>
      </element>
   </orders>
</root>
```

as you can see `customerId` and `elid` are xml attributes not elements.

So I had to use the below to fix it,

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "customerNumber")  //will map to @customerNumber in JSON
@XmlAttribute(name = "elid")            //will map to @elid in JSON
```